# Should we split each state/contract by each cordapp

Tags: corda

With the contract upgrade in mind, is it better to split each state and contract to its own cordapp/module so it exist in its own jar when deployed?

Hence during upgrade, we can upgrade only the affected states - instead of have N number of states in one shared-cordapp, and when only one state is upgraded, we have to upgraded all other states as well.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you initially deploy the following CorDapps on your node:

- **CorDapp 1**, containing `OldState1`, `OldState2`, `OldContract1`, `OldContract2`
- **CorDapp 2**, containing `OldState3`, `OldState4`, `OldContract3`, `OldContract4`

After running the node for a while, you need to upgrade `OldState1` to `NewState1`, and `OldContract1` to `NewContract1`.

To do so, you create a new CorDapp JAR containing `NewState1` and `NewContract1` and deploy this on your node. You can then initiate the upgrade process to transition the `OldState1` instances using `OldContract1` to instances of `NewState1` using `NewContract1`.

In other words, although your original CorDapp contained two states and two contracts, the CorDapp containing the upgrades only needs to contain one state and one contract. There is therefore no advantage to splitting each contract and state into its own CorDapp as you describe.